# How can I create different spring beans depending on the input

Tags: java, spring

All the class are implemented from the same interface. What is the best way to create beans depending on the input value we are receiving.

If the value is a it need to invoke one class vs different class if the value is b.

Answer (score 0):

You cloud try something like this:

```
    @Component
public class SomeServiceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Someservice someserviceA;

    @Autowired
    private Someservice someserviceB;

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceThree SomeserviceC;

    public SomeService getSomeService(String serviceType) {         

        if (serviceType.equals("A")) {
            return someserviceA;
        } else if (serviceType.equals("B")) {
            return someserviceB;
        } else {
            return someserviceC;
        } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First the interface:

```
public interface MyService {
    void doSomething();
}
```

2. Then defining two implementation:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceA implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do your business A
    }
}

@Service
public class MyServiceB implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do your business B
    }
}
```

3. The context:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class MyServiceContext {
    private final Map<String, MyService> strategyMap;

    public MyService getMyService(String key) {
        // the key is the bean name
        return strategyMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

4. Usage

```
@Autowired
private MyServiceContext context;
...
// your input key must be the bean name.
context.getMyService(yourInputValue).doSmething();
```